# best port (on laptop) for using laptop display as monitor for an Amiga

Tags: amiga, display, laptop

i am looking to order an Amiga 500.  i wanted to use my Thinkpad L420's display as a monitor, but it seems it doesn't have a port that would work for that.  the thinkpad needs replacing anyways, so i am wondering what i should look for when shopping for a laptop which i intend to use also as a display for an Amiga.  i ask because it seems the options for a working display for an Amiga are multiple and complicated.

Comment: Retro computers and consoles (like Amiga) have analog video signals not directly compatible to any modern laptop input. You'd have to use a video capture device to capture the analog signal and display it in a window. Such devices are commonly used by video streamers, like on Twitch, so this is "nothing special".

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question, since this is about trying to use a laptop display for displaying an external video source (which is non-trivial). BTW, your best bet is a capture card, but beware of latency.